# Javascript this and that with callbacks

Tags: javascript, this

When using `var that = this` for callbacks, why does the callback function have to be `function() {that.myFn()}` instead of `that.myFn` ?

For example:

```
var obj = {

  foo: function(fn) {
    console.log('--foo--', this);
    fn();
  },

  bar: function() {
    console.log('--bar--', this);
  },

  render: function() {
    var that = this;

    // this line works
    this.foo( function() {that.bar()} );

    // this line doesn't work
    this.foo(that.bar);
  }

}

obj.render()
```

Comment: `this.foo(this.bar.bind(this));` will also work, by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you invoke a function on a property like

```
myObject.myFunction();
```

it automatically binds the `this` value to that object, whereas simply getting a reference to that function object like so:

```
var x = myObject.myFunction;
x();
```

does not imply any "this". The first statement simply sets x to the same function as is referenced by that property of myObject.

wrapping it in a function like so:

```
var x = function(){ myObject.myFunction()};
x();
```

does invoke myFunction with myObject as bound to "this".

You can also use the javascript Function.prototype functions "call", "apply", and "bind", instead, like so:

```
var x = myObject.myFunction.bind(myObject, parameterOneIfAny);
x();
```

which returns a function with an explicitly bound "this" value of "myObject". Its just a part of the javascript function system that function objects don't save a "this" context (or rather default `this` to the environment "global" object in cases where you don't set `this`) unless invoked with property syntax `object.function()` or explicitly bound with `object.function.bind(object)`

finally, if you call any function reference with `new` as in

```
var x = myObject.myFunction.bind(myObject, parameterOneIfAny);
var y = new x();
```

`this` is instantiated as a fresh object, and passed as the return value, which is the basis for javascript's fake "class" syntax. So in this case, x is invoked as a constructor, and its `this` value is returned, making y a 'new' x.

Finally, javascript strict mode will call you out if you try to use `this` in a function that has not been invoked with a `this` context, rather than the non-strict behavior of defaulting `this` to the `window` object.

Comment: Nice and explicit, thanks. Any references? I couldn't find this on MDN.

Comment: I'll edit my comment to have less ambiguous terminology, and I'll add here that every function has a "this" context, but it usually just defaults to "window" or the global environment variable in cases where you fail to bind one, but as for links:

[mdsn this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)  ,  ---  [mdsn bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Got it. I guess I was looking for your second example (showing the wrong way) in the MDN article, which is what really cleared things up for me.

Comment: glad those articles helped. Ive edited my comment to contain a bit more info but I can't claim to be an expert on `this`, and have never used strict mode.

Comment: arrow functions don't have a `this` or `arguments`, they inherit those from the parent scopes, or if none of the parent scopes are a function, attempting to access `this` or `arguments` will throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why is because `that.bar()` is the same thing as [`bar.call(that)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), but `fn()` is the same as `fn.call(undefined)`, and [in loose mode, `undefined` becomes the global context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Simple_call), which is `window`.

Comment: So in general, passing function definitions like `that.myFn` has no purpose?

Comment: @jim You could instead do [`this.foo(that.bar.bind(that));`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: yeah, I've also found `this.foo(this.bar.bind(this));` also works. So there's no reason to ever pass `that.myFn` on it's own?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts At the risk of a bad pun, if you do this you don't need `that`. You could just do `this.foo( this.bar.bind(this) );` and remove the `var that = this;`.

Comment: @jim You beat me to it by a minute. :-) Yes, you are correct.

Comment: I know you didn't need `that`. It's in the same scope, I was just being consistent with the example.

Answer (score -1):

As @slackOverflow says. Here a link that will help to understand
[https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referen‌ce/Operators/this](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referen%E2%80%8Cce/Operators/this)

or try this. It's a nice post that may help too.
[http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javas‌​cript](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javas%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcript)